# Request Value always getting null in PHP 5.4 API

Tags: php, ajax, api, php-5.4

In below code, value not meet when its calling using Ajax.
$pos always return null value

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('data-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
           //error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("connect.php");
include("datalayer.php");
$pos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$InvalidLogon =(array) new \stdClass();
?>
```

AJAX Call

```
var settings = {
  "url": "login.php",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"emp_id":"emp1","password":"password"}),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: The value of `$pos` is never written in the output : `echo  $pos;`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code

```
$pos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

with

```
echo $pos = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```